# Why don't my child processes inherit the global context when multiprocessing Pool is employed over a function from another module?

Tags: python, scope, python-multiprocessing

I'm running my code on Linux and the process start method is 'fork'. Thus I expect child processes to inherit the global context of python module (testfile.py) which I am executing. This module imports a function (nestedfunc) from another module (testfile2.py) and passes it to multiprocessing Pool.

I expect the child processes to inherit the globals of testfile.py, but when I call globals() from inside nestedfunc, what I get is the global context of testfile2.py

The code is as follows, two files in a project root dir:

testfile.py

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import current_process, get_start_method
print(f'''new process start method: {get_start_method()}''')

a = 1

from testfile2 import nested_func

def func():
    jobs = 2
    if current_process().name == 'MainProcess':
        with Pool(jobs) as p:
            p.map(nested_func, [1, 2])

def parallelfunc():
    func()

if current_process().name == 'MainProcess':
    parallelfunc()
```

testfile2.py

```
import os
def nested_func(*args):
    print(f'''process {os.getpid()} with parent {os.getppid()} inside nestedfunc has global a in globals: {'a' in globals()}''')
```

I get

> new process start method: fork process 3659 with parent 3658 inside nestedfunc has global a in globals: False
> process 3660 with parent 3658 inside nestedfunc has global a in globals: False

while what I'm expecting is True. What am I missing?

Comment: "I expect the child processes to inherit the globals of testfile.py, but when I call globals() from inside nestedfunc, what I get is the global context of testfile2.py" **of course**. This has nothing to do with multiprocessing, `globals()` will always give you the globals *of the module where it was called*. Also note, even though you are using fork, the state is only shared in a COW manner, but in Python, just referencing an object involves write, so effectively (barring certain exceptions) it's not sharing state

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for answering. Why the state isn't shared and how to make  it shared? What I do want is to access some variables from main module

Comment: the state is *copied*.  It isn't shared because they are *in separate processes*. This is all clear documented in the multiprocessing docs. If you really must *share* state, then it has various approaches there (although this significantly complicates things). In any case, this has **nothing** to do with the behavior you are seeing, please understand, this is simply how the `globals()` function *always works*. If you *remove* multiprocessing from the example so everything is in the same process sharing the same state, you get the same behavior

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you. I checked out how does the import system work and found the way to achieve what I wanted to. Since the question doesn't have to do anything with the example I provided, I guess it should be deleted.